# makefiles implicit and explicit rule

Tags: gnu-make

I have a rule

```
*.o: *.c
    gcc <certain compiler switches>
```

I would like to build a few *.c files with different compiler switches than the standard rule.

I believe I simply add before the first rule

```
foo.o : foo.c
foobar.o : foobar.c
    gcc <other compiler switches>
```

Does the explicit rule of foo and foobar override the *.o : *.c rule?

Comment: Have you tried it? Q: Are `<other compiler switches>` supposed to apply to `foo.o` as well as `foobar.o`?

Comment: Yes, foo.o and foobar.o are to have the same compiler switches, but different than *.o: *.c.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with your makefile. `*.o: *.c` uses shell wildcards and is almost certainly not what you want. You are probably wanting to write a pattern rules using make wildcards—`%.o: %.c`. I don't like these much (pattern rules that is). I always like to be very explicit in my makefiles. Something like:

```
SRCS := foo.c foobar.c
OBJS := ${SRCS:%.c=%.o}

${OBJS}: %.o: %.c
    gcc ${OPTS-${@D}} $< -o $@
```

Now you can define `OPTS-foo` and `OPTS-foobar` as you see fit.